# Google location search works on android but not in ios

Tags: ionic3, google-places-autocomplete

I try to fill address inputs on an ionic3 form with the google autocomplete location search. It works fine on android but not perfectly on iOs.
On iOs when I choose an address on the google list, sometimes it fills the input and sometimes not...
Is there something wrong in my code ?

Thanks

```html
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-input placeholder="> Adresse complète et choisir" id="locationsearch" type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <!---Input field address-->
                    <ion-item class="disabled">
                        <ion-input [disabled]="true" required placeholder="Champs réservé" type="text"
                                   formControlName="address"
                                   [(ngModel)]="userData.address"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <!---Input field zipcode-->
                    <ion-item class="disabled">
                        <ion-input [disabled]="true" required placeholder="Champs réservé" type="text"
                                   formControlName="zipcode"
                                   [(ngModel)]="userData.zipcode"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <!---Input field city-->
                    <ion-item class="disabled">
                        <ion-input [disabled]="true" required placeholder="Champs réservé" type="text" class="text-disabled"
                                   formControlName="city"
                                   [(ngModel)]="userData.city"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
```

```js
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        let that = this;
        var options = {
          componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"}
        };

        let currentlocationinput = document.getElementById('locationsearch').childNodes[1];
        let currentlocationsearchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(currentlocationinput, options);

        currentlocationsearchBox.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = currentlocationsearchBox.getPlace();
          // Remplir les autres champs
          that.userData.address = place.address_components[0].short_name+" "+place.address_components[1].short_name;
          that.userData.zipcode = place.address_components[6].short_name;
          that.userData.city = place.address_components[2].short_name;
          that.ref.detectChanges();
        });
      }
```